# Is there a way to rollout a deployment by modify Kubernetes Object Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I can not find a way to rollout my deployment directly like `kubectl rollout undo xxx` in a third-party k8s-client called fabric, but the client offers the way to modify k8s objects.
so I'm wondering if there is a way to rollout a deployment by modify Kubernetes Object Deployment?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do something like that in the fabric8 kubernetes-client.
So you will have to simulate the `kubectl rollout` command using the client to modify the Deployment object (pretty much as you described).

This is however a really neat feature and I am sure that it wouldn't be that hard to add to the client.
I can see that you've already raised an issue about it, so we can take it from there.